# Bindings on directive with Isolate scope not in scope sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have a **directive** with **isolate scope** and a **controllerAs** pattern.

```
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            something: '='
        },
        templateUrl: './App/directiveTemplate.html',
        controller: directiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    }
```

and in the controller I init with a call to a REST service using **$http** that returns a promise.

```
 function directiveController(someService) {

    var vm = this;

    // Here vm.something is defined and bound to the appropriate model set where the directive is used

    init()

    function init() {
        return someService.getProducts()
        .then(productsReady);

        function productsReady(response) {
            vm.products = response;
            //find product using vm.something

            // here vm.something is undefined

           return vm.products;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I breakpoint before the `init()` method `vm.something` is defined like it should be but in the `productsReady` function it is undefined.

Is that a normal behaviour? Is the promise resolving code in a different scope?

Comment: The `productsReady()` function is defined within the `init()` method. It's local to that scope. Why would you expect it to be defined outside of `init()`?

Comment: Are you seeking to understand javascript variable scope? Or is there something you're trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: @JCFord I'm no Javascript expert. The init method has access to the scope, so I assumed a method defined inside init would also have access in a inheritance sort of way. Guess that isn't true?

Comment: @JCFord Something that isn't working, but I guess I need to understand scopes better.

Comment: I think I misread your question. So `vm.something` has a value before `init()` runs, but not when the `getProducts` promise resolves. The `productsReady` function will certainly have access to the `vm` and all its properties. There must be something happening between calling `getProducts` and it resolving. Can you share the full controller?

Comment: I've got to run, but I guess you are right, because it seems to get undefined at some point as it still is undefined later on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`$onInit` Life-Cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) to guarantee the timing of bindings:

```
 function directiveController(someService) {

    var vm = this;

    ̶i̶n̶i̶t̶(̶)̶

    this.$onInit = init;

    function init() {
        return someService.getProducts()
        .then(productsReady);

        function productsReady(data) {
            vm.products = data;

           return vm.products;
        }
    }
```

From the Docs:

> Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called *after* the bindings have been assigned.
>
> ```
> .component('myComponent', {
>   bindings: {value: '<'},
>   controller: function() {
>     this.$onInit = function() {
>       // `this.value` will always be initialized,
>       // regardless of the value of `preAssignBindingsEnabled`.
>       this.doubleValue = this.value * 2;
>     };
>   }
> })
> ```
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-bcd0d4)

Comment: I'll take a look at this, but I think the bindings are actually resolve, but get undefined of some different reason. But this is a good idea anyways and probably how I should be doing it.

Comment: This is a canonical answer for other users that are having the problem described in the title. Your question as written does not provide enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: True, my problem must lie on the other side of the binding somewhere. I didn't write the code I'm working on so I will have to take a look. But perhaps I should just mark this as a answer for later browsers.